# Grep multiple sql files for appsand(&) and the word after it (the variable name)

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep multiple SQL scripts for variables in the format of `&"variable name"`.  For example, if I have two files `intl_reg.sql` and `trans_by_detc.sql`, with the variables in the `intl_reg.sql` file of

```
&campus     
&level  
&ptc    
&visa   
&term   
&sort
```

and in the file `trans_by_detc.sql`,

```
&detc       
&date1   
&date2   
&credits
```

I would like to have it listed and written to a file like the below

```
intl_reg.sql campus level ptc visa term sort
trans_by_detc.sql detc date1 date2 credits
```

Is this possible with `grep`?

Comment: Jonathan, as for your previous question, please learn how to format code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -nE '$v{$1}++ while /&(\w+)/g; END{say join " ", sort keys%v}' your-file
```

Would print a sorted list of the unique sequences of ASCII word characters that follow a `&` anywhere in `your-file`.

To process all `sql` files in the current working directory:

```
perl -nE '$a{$1}++ while /&(\w+)/g;
          if (eof) {
            say join " ", $ARGV, sort keys%a; undef %a
          }' ./*.sql
```

Comment: Perl is not on all Unix* AFAIK. But if present, yes, it's portable. I doubt Android have Perl by default, nor `nixos`

Comment: How would I write the results to a file?

Answer (score 1):

With **GNU** `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '^&\K\w+' file | paste -sd ' ' -
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `&` | & |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

---

Or with usual `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '[[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}' file | paste -sd ' ' -
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `[[:alnum:]_]` | any character of: letters and digits, '_' |
| `\{1,\}` | at least one time |

Works on :

- Solaris 11
- FreeBSD 13.1-
- BusyBox
- NixOs
- Alpine `ash` shell
- ...

##### Output

```
campus level ptc visa term sort
```

#### With full OP needs

```
$ for s in intl_reg.sql trans_by_detc.sql; do
      printf '%s\n' "$s $(grep -o '[[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}' "$s" | paste -sd ' ' -)"
  done
```

```
intl_reg.sql campus level ptc visa term sort
trans_by_detc.sql detc date1 date2 credits
```

Comment: How would you do it with standard grep?

Comment: Added _legacy grep_ way

Comment: `-o` and `\+` are also GNU extensions.

Comment: See `[[:alnum:]_]` as the standard equivalent to `\w`. Standard equivalent of `\+` is `\{1,\}`, though you can also use `+` with `-E`. There's no standard equivalent for `-o`.

Comment: FreeBSD have `-o`, even Solaris 11

Comment: Even `busybox` have `-o`

Comment: Yes, FreeBSD's grep used to be GNU grep. They rewrote it at some point keeping the same API as in the version of GNU grep they were using for backward compatibility. The API of busybox utilities is inspired by the GNU implementations. Many implementations have copied `-o` indeed from GNU `grep`, some in a not fully compatible way like ast-open grep which runs into infinite loop if the regex matches the empty string. See also toybox' grep (like on Android) that outputs `a` 3 times in `echo aaa | grep -o '^a'`

Comment: I don't think I quite explained enough of my issue.  All of the comments are helpful.  So far what I have that is close is grep -o  '\&[a-z]*' trans_by_detc.sql .  However, I need to exclude the & in the results and I only want to list a variable once.  I have several &date in the SQL file and only want one displayed.  If possible I would also like the list in a single row rather than multiple rows.

Comment: Using now `paste` to have all ine one line @Jonathan